# Catch "The program stopped working" on Vista 

Tags: c, windows-vista

On Vista, I got a problem with the application crash handler. Basically, if something unexpected occurs which cannot be captured by SEH, I get this pop-up window with "The application stopped working", blablabla, "Close program/Debug program" -- that is, after I disable the error reporting using the system control panel. With error reporting enabled, you would get a task dialog with search for solution online, close, debug.

This is not so funny if it happens in automated tools, and I wonder whether there is a way to get rid of it *totally*, read, if my app crashes, it just crashes to the command line or disappears but does not bring up a dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(0)|SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
```

But I would suggest to install an exceptions handler which creates a dump so you can verify what happened. For example [crashrpt](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/) (or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/crash_report.aspx)).

See also

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Function [signal](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node24.html) works on all POSIX platforms:

```
signal(SIGSEGV, &signal_handler);
```

If you need to trap an exception that isn't supported by signal, you can also take a look at [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679274(VS.85).aspx), a function specific to W32.