# c# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

**I have a running windows service.** I would like to **monitor a c# console application** from the **windows service**. My c# console application reads and writes in the console a sum, multiplication. **I would like to open and work with my console application using my windows service**. What should i write **in OnStart() method** in order to execute properly my c# code.

I did put in windows service the exe file (Process.start()) from my console application code but i have the error: **console application stopped from working**. WHY? please help me:). **I know windows services do not work with GUI applications**. But I just want to open from my windows service another application (my exe that contains my console app). THX

Can someone give me a little eq that works?:). Thx

Comment: Do you want to open the console to debug?  Or just open an external app?

Comment: Have you debugged the console application to make sure _that_ is functioning properly?

Comment: It is possible for a Windows Service to have some UI. You need to ensure the service is grated the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' setting.

Comment: yes. The console application wuns properly. I've tested it.

Comment: @tomas: No, it's not possible. That checkbox stopped working way back in Windows XP. That was over 10 years ago.

Comment: Yes I just want to open another process using windows service. I guess is something like monitor another process

Comment: Cody, can you not use the NotifyIcon class and have that open UI? I've used that in Windows XP, and its still supported in .Net 4.0. Just a thought.

Comment: @tomas: What does the `NotifyIcon` class have to do with Windows Services? This doesn't have anything to do with the version of .NET, and everything to do with the tightened security model introduced with Windows Vista (and still there in Windows 7). They're finally closing some of the gaping security holes in Windows. It's amazing how many developers this catches off their guard.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just GUI applications that don't work with Windows Services. Console applications have the same problem. They still run as a user-mode process, to which a Windows Service does not have access. Services run in a completely isolated process space called Session 0. They don't have access to the desktop of any user account, and they can't interact with applications running on those desktops.

Aside from that, console applications still show a user interface. The command prompt window that pops up on the screen still counts, even if it's not graphical. Launched from a Windows Service, it has no place to pop up.

This is a security feature of Windows Vista and later. The "Enable service to interact with desktop" checkbox doesn't work anymore, and it hasn't since Windows XP. You weren't supposed to use it there, either. Isolation protects Windows Services from attacks that originate in application code.

Like almost every other time I see people asking questions like this, it's not clear why you need to use a Windows Service in the first place. The simpler option is to create a Windows application that doesn't show any forms, and run it in the background. This creates an effect very similar to a Windows Service, but without the limitations you're experiencing. Because it's still running in the current user's space, it can launch and control other user mode applications.

Related reading:

- [How can a Windows Service start a process when a Timer event is raised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516200/how-can-a-windows-service-start-a-process-when-a-timer-event-is-raised/4516515#4516515)
- [How can I run an EXE program from a Windows Service using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307968/how-can-i-run-an-exe-program-from-a-windows-service-using-c/5308011#5308011)
- [windows service (allow service to interact with desktop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237225/windows-service-allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop/4237283#4237283)
- [Need suggestion on replacing Windows Service by invisible WinForm Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813138/need-suggestion-on-replacing-windows-service-by-invisible-winform-application/4813184#4813184)

Comment: But that can't run while nobody is logged on.

Comment: i need a windows service that monitors somehow my app.

Comment: @Dont: Right, applications can't run when no one is logged in. Windows Services can't interact with logged-on users. The computer can't do anything at all when it is turned off. This problem is unsolvable.

Comment: You can solve the first two by having a service and an invisible forms application communicate, for example over wcf

Answer (score 0):

Does your console application log any errors? Perhaps try checking the error logs to see what might be the cause of the console app issue. This question may guide you to an answer/fix:

[Avoid Program Stopped Working in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421597/avoid-program-stopped-working-in-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has some issues, as you mention, most windows servers block services directly accessing the GUI, as well as a service runs as its own instance of a user rather than any the one logged in. As a result, accessing a user run application is difficult if not impossible (just as the same way it cant see your user directories)

What is more feasible is the reverse.

If you have a service which your console app wishes to interact with, it could announce its arrival, and then on connection the service can reply with instructions for your console app to carry out. But, you would need to devise a structual method of doing so.

Comment: @elisa You could make the service start a wcf service over a named pipe.

Comment: please guid me...:) a short eq with some explications would help a lot